# Electron + ReactJS + Material-UI Rendering Glitches

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, electron, material-ui

I'm working on a desktop app based on Electron + ReactJS + Redux + [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) + Webpack. Everything runs fine except some Material-UI components, like `<IconMenu />` and `<CircularProgress />`. These elements are not rendered properly by Electron, however they work fine in Chrome Browser.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: <IconMenu /> got]

instead of

[image: <IconMenu /> expected]

[image: <CircularProgress /> got]

instead of

[image: <CircularProgress /> expected]

I've no idea why it's happening so as custom transitions works fine but I actually think that the issue is that they are using SVG elements that are not being rendered correctly. However, custom-loaded SVG works fine.

That's really annoying and I spent a lot of time to handle it with no result, so finally I'm here asking for help.

Comment: `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` use chrome debug bar to inspect the element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Luckily the issue is solved with updating Electron to version **1.8.0.**